# How to update a date range in multiple areas of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to update the date ranges for all queries below (August 1 - August 31, 2019) to September 1 - 30, 2019 without having to manually change them all. Any ideas?

Here are the two queries I have:

--MTD Gross Charges

```
SELECT 
'$' + CONVERT(varchar,CAST(SUM(TX_AMOUNT) AS money),1) AS [HB Charges ($)]
FROM HSP_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE TX_POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31'
AND TX_TYPE_HA_C = '1'
```

--MTD Cash Collections

```
SELECT
'$' + CONVERT(varchar,cast(SUM(TX_AMOUNT *-1) -
    (SELECT
    SUM(TX_AMOUNT *-1) 
    FROM HSP_TRANSACTIONS 
    WHERE TX_POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31'
    AND TX_TYPE_HA_C = '2'
    AND BAD_DEBT_FLAG_YN = 'Y'
    GROUP BY TX_TYPE_HA_C) AS money),1) AS [HB Payments ($)]
FROM HSP_TRANSACTIONS 
WHERE TX_POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31'
AND TX_TYPE_HA_C = '2'
GROUP BY TX_TYPE_HA_C
```

Since I run these queries (and more) monthly, I'm looking for a simple way to change all instances of

```
WHERE TX_POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-08-31'
```

to

```
WHERE TX_POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-09-01' AND '2019-09-30'
```

... then next month to

```
WHERE TX_POST_DATE BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31'
```

Comment: Create 2 parameters, `StartDate` and `EndDate` and calculate the beginning and ending days of the previous month?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set up the logic to run for the current month?

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(varchar,CAST(SUM(TX_AMOUNT) AS money),1) AS [HB Charges ($)]
FROM HSP_TRANSACTIONS
WHERE TX_POST_DATE >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
      TX_POST_DATE < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) AND
      TX_TYPE_HA_C = '1'
```

Then the code will just run for the current month.  Or you can subtract another month if you want to run it for the previous month.

For the previous month, you would use:

```
WHERE TX_POST_DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) AND
      TX_POST_DATE < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)) AND
```